# SFML with Code::Blocks - "undefined reference to sf::Texture::getSize()"

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, sfml

I used this tutorial http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php to add SFML to my Code::Blocks project, but I got errors like that:

```
undefined reference to sf::Texture::getSize() const
undefined reference to sf::Sprite::Sprite()
undefined reference to sf::Sprite::setTexture(sf::Texture const&, bool)
```

Here are the screenshots from my settings:

The liner settings:
[image]

The search directories for compiler:
[image]

The search directories for linker:
[image]

The compiler settings:
[image]

```
||=== Build: Release in Space (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::Sprite()'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::setTexture(sf::Texture const&, bool)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::setPosition(float, float)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::Sprite()'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::setTexture(sf::Texture const&, bool)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::setPosition(float, float)'
 undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'
 undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'
 undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::~Transformable()'
 (.text$_ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev[__ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev]+0x3e)
undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 (.text$_ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev[__ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev]+0x45)
undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 (.text$_ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev[__ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev]+0x57)
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::~Transformable()'|
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined references to `sf::Texture::getSize() const' follow
 undefined reference to `sf::Clock::Clock()'
 undefined reference to `sf::seconds(float)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Time::Time()'
 undefined reference to `sf::operator<(sf::Time, sf::Time)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Time::Zero'
 undefined reference to `sf::Time::Zero'
 undefined reference to `sf::Clock::restart()'
 undefined reference to `sf::operator+=(sf::Time&, sf::Time)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Texture::getSize() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::Sprite()'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::setTexture(sf::Texture const&, bool)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::setPosition(float, float)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::Sprite()'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::setTexture(sf::Texture const&, bool)'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::setPosition(float, float)'
 undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'
 undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates  const&)'|
 undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 undefined reference to `vtable for sf::Sprite'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::~Transformable()'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::getGlobalBounds() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::getTextureRect() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::getScale() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Transformable::getTransform() const'
 undefined reference to `sf::Sprite::getTextureRect() const'
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Did you follow the linker instructions in that tutorial?  Because you're apparently not linking against the libraries.

Comment: @mbgda I was trying to go step-by-step with the tutorial, also with the linker instructions

Comment: All we can tell from what you posted is that you're not linking against the libraries.  We don't know any of the pertinent information about how you've set up your project.  Are you trying to link in the static or dynamic libraries?  what are your linker settings?  Etc.

Comment: Please provide the build log.

Comment: This shouldn't cause a linker error, but you've defined SFML_STATIC yet it seems you're linking against the dynamic libraries (according to the documentation you linked, the statics are named LIBNAME-s for RELEASE and LIBNAME-s-d for DEBUG)

Comment: @mbgda I corrected this - but  still the same errors

Comment: You probably also need to reorder sfml-audio and sfml-network above sfml-system since they depend on it.  Not sure that will fix the linker error, but it may.

Comment: Also, once you've gotten your program to link, make sure you follow this instruction: _If you are using the sfml-audio module (regardless whether statically or dynamically), you must also copy the DLLs of the external libraries needed by it, which are libsndfile-1.dll and OpenAL32.dll.
These files can be found in <sfml-install-path/bin> too._

Comment: @mbgda Unfortunately it didn't solve a problem...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  You need to get the correct version of the sfml libs (one that was compiled with the exact same compiler version you're using in your project).

Comment: codeblocks 13.12 with mingw file includes the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.7.1, 32 bit)

Comment: Did you download the corresponding version of sfml from here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/ ?

Comment: If all else fails, since it looks like you're linking statically anyway, you could always just get the SFML source and compile it into your project, which will get around any toolchain mismatch issues.

Comment: Edit, for what it's worth, I just tried your exact same setup and I got it to work with code blocks 13.12 and SFML GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out your issue.  I suspect you need to download SFML GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit from here http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/ - you were probably using the wrong version of the libs.